# There's a lot more to me than just my money

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Are the following sentences correct?

- "There's a lot **more to** life than just looking good."
- "There's a lot more to me than just my money."

What does 'there's a lot more to me' exactly mean?

Another similar sentence I've heard:

- "I don't know how much truth there is to it."

I know it's a different kind of sentence but I think both talk about the quality of someone/something. To be honest I'm not even sure if this one's correct.

Answer (score 1):

All three sentences seem correct to me, or at least, idiomatic.

The idiom *there's more to X than Y* essentially means X is not solely made up of Y, but has other "ingredients": a very literal example being "there's more to cake than eggs".  Yes, there are eggs in cake, but eggs alone do not make cake, there is also flour and so on.

It tends to be used not just in terms of the physical make-up of X, but the notable / beneficial qualities of X.

So "There's (a lot) more to me than my money" means "I have more to offer [as a friend/lover/business partner/etc] than just being rich", with the implication they are also clever/funny/talented/etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. What about "I don't know how much truth there is to it?" Is it something a native speaker would say?

Comment: Yes.  Pretty much means the same as "I don't know how true it is".